# Inserting values into database multiple tables through C# windows application

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

```
private void btnsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string dbpath = @"Data Source=ABC;Initial Catalog=ApplicationForm;Integrated Security=True";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(dbpath);
            con.Open();
            string savequerybscs="insert into bscs values('"+txtapplicantnumber.Text+"','"+txtname.Text+"','"+txtfathername.Text+"','"+txtmatrictotal.Text+"','"+txtmatricobtained.Text+"','"+txtmatricpercent.Text+"','"+txtintertotal.Text+"','"+txtinterobtained.Text+ "','"+txtinterpercent.Text+"')";
            string savequerybsit ="insert into bsit values('" + txtapplicantnumber.Text + "','" + txtname.Text + "','" + txtfathername.Text + "','" + txtmatrictotal.Text + "','" + txtmatricobtained.Text + "','" + txtmatricpercent.Text + "','" + txtintertotal.Text + "','" + txtinterobtained.Text + "','" + txtinterpercent.Text + "')";
            string savequerymcs ="insert into bscs values('" + txtapplicantnumber.Text + "','" + txtname.Text + "','" + txtfathername.Text + "','" + txtmatrictotal.Text + "','" + txtmatricobtained.Text + "','" + txtmatricpercent.Text + "','" + txtintertotal.Text + "','" + txtinterobtained.Text + "','" + txtinterpercent.Text + "','"+txtbachelortotal.Text+"','"+txtbachelorobtained.Text+"','"+txtbachelorpercent.Text+"')";
            string savequerymit ="insert into bscs values('" + txtapplicantnumber.Text + "','" + txtname.Text + "','" + txtfathername.Text + "','" + txtmatrictotal.Text + "','" + txtmatricobtained.Text + "','" + txtmatricpercent.Text + "','" + txtintertotal.Text + "','" + txtinterobtained.Text + "','" + txtinterpercent.Text + "','" + txtbachelortotal.Text + "','" + txtbachelorobtained.Text + "','" + txtbachelorpercent.Text + "')";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(savequerybscs,savequerymcs,bla blaa);

        }
```

[image: this is the GUI from which data should be inserted into specified separate tables in the SQL server for BSCS, BSIT, MCS and MIT]

As you can see, this solution is pretty messed up. Is there any other way to handle such issues? All I want is to insert data in multiple tables simultaneously but `SqlCommand` only takes 1 argument.
I just learned about bulk query or bulk insertion. Can someone guide me through that? I am not clearly getting those concepts from youtube.

Comment: how about `SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(savequerybscs + " "+ savequerymcs+ " "+ bla + " "+blaa);`

Comment: @Sajid zahiri taur py tou masla nahi show krrha, lemme run it :)

Comment: You should assign Command text property of the command to one query then execute it, then assign another query and then execute it. That's how you can execute multiple queries using single command object.

Answer (score 0):

You can do one insert query using the comma separator between tuples for multiples rows:

```
insert into bsit values (field1, field2...), (field1, field2...), ...
```

But this insert is for one table.

Basically, you use as many SQL query as many table you want to update.

I'm not advanced but perhaps, depending on the database server, you could execute a "script" in one C# SqlCommand execute non query call, using the semilicon separator, like:

```
string sql = "insert into table1 values (field1, field2...), (field1, field2...), ... ; "
           + "insert into table2 values (field1, field2...), (field1, field2...), ... ;";
```

MySql should support that.

You should use SQL Parameters for security reason instead of adding values to the sql string itself:

```
string sql = "insert into table1 values (?, ?)";

var command = new OdbcCommand(sql, connection);

command.Parameters.Add("@ID", OdbcType.Text).Value = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
command.Parameters.Add("@Name", OdbcType.Text).Value = "Test";

command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters

Comment: your suggested query would insert all the data but i have a case where data is not inserted in every table but one do i need if else for that ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean neither of the case you mention.

Comment: i tried to elaborate my issue more by adding a GUI hope you can get the code a bit better now  *i am a reaaaally newbie"

Comment: The image of GUI does not explain which data should be inserted and which should not be inserted. Can you explain the logic in the question itself? @ashiqpervez